# Unable to get React Form values

Tags: reactjs, forms

I created a form with react-semantic and then I tried to parse in a database the fields through json. But I can't get the values. My form code is:

```
 class FormPatient extends Component {
      state = {}

      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          patient: {
            firstName: '',
            lastName: '' } }}

      onFirstNameChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({firstName: event.target.value});  }

      onLastNameChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({lastName: event.target.value});}

      onSubmit = () => {
        console.log(this.state);
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/', {
          method: 'post',
          headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
          body: JSON.stringify({
            firstName: this.state.firstName,
            lastName: this.state.lastName })})
        .then(response => response.json())
         .then(patient => {
           if (patient) {
              console.log(patient);
              this.props.loadPatient(this.state.patient)  }}) }

     render() {
        const { value } = this.state
        return ( 
            <Form>
              <Form.Group widths='equal'>
                <Form.Field 
                  control={Input} 
                  label='First name' 
                  placeholder='First name' 
                  onChange={this.onFirstNameChange}/>
                <Form.Field 
                  control={Input} 
                  label='Last name' 
                  placeholder='Last name' 
                  onChange={this.onLastNameChange}/>
               </Form.Group>
           </Form>)}}

    export default FormPatient
```

The first console.log gets the values -> {patient: {…}, firstName: "asg", lastName: "asgd"}
but the second after the fetch can't -> {firstName: "", lastName: ""}
 The loadPatient function is in App file.

```
 loadPatient = (data) => {
            this.setState({patient: {
              id: data.id,
              firstName: data.firstName,
              lastName: data.lastName,
              joined: data.joined}})}
```

Comment: the first console.log is console.log(this.state); and the second one is               console.log(patient); ?

Comment: @sofia I updated my solution. Give a try now

Comment: with regards to loadPatient first let us know what you get as a response in fetch call. the reason in loadPatient you are also looking for id and joined

Answer (score 0):

The reason it was not working because you have firstName and lastName inside patient object in the state inside constructr but you are accessing like this.state.firstName and this.state.lastName in onSubmit so it won't work.

Also you are not passing onSubmit props to Form so when you submit your form onSubmit won't trigger.

Please try with below updated code

```
    class FormPatient extends Component {

      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            patient: {
                firstName: '',
                lastName: ''
            } 
        }
      }

      onFirstNameChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({patient: {
            firstName: event.target.value
           }
        });  
      }

      onLastNameChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({patient: {
            lastName: event.target.value
           }
        });
      }

      onSubmit = (event) => {
        console.log(this.state);
        event.preventDefault();
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/', {
          method: 'post',
          headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
          body: JSON.stringify({
            firstName: this.state.firstName,
            lastName: this.state.lastName })})
        .then(response => response.json())
         .then(patient => {
           if (patient) {
              console.log(patient);
              this.props.loadPatient(this.state.patient)  }}) }

     render() {
        const { value } = this.state
        return ( 
            <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
              <Form.Group widths='equal'>
                <Form.Field 
                  control={Input} 
                  label='First name' 
                  placeholder='First name' 
                  onChange={this.onFirstNameChange}/>
                <Form.Field 
                  control={Input} 
                  label='Last name' 
                  placeholder='Last name' 
                  onChange={this.onLastNameChange}/>
               </Form.Group>
           </Form>)}}

    export default FormPatient
```